# C# LINQ getting duplicates from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that have a string, and int and another int.
I want to be able to create a list of all the objects that have a duplicate string.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 MyObject duplicates = allMyObjects.GroupBy(a => a.MyString)
            .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
            .ToList();
```

The error I am getting is that I cannot implicitly convert the type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string, MyObject> to MyObject`

Comment: Well, that seems obvious, I suspect `MyObject` doesn't extend `List`? You could always write `var duplicates`.

Comment: (Even if it `MyObject` did extend List it would be an invalid assignment.)

Comment: what is `MyObject` and `allMyObjects` ?

Comment: What is the type of allMyObjects?

Comment: Even when I do that, when I loop through the list and try to cast back into a MyObject it will throw the same error?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, if you have - for example `{'A',1,1},{'A',2,2},{'B',3,3}`, what would be your _exact_ desired result? Both A entries? Either of them? Just the string `A`?

Comment: Also, please post the *real* error message, that is not it.. List takes one type parameter; you omitted an IGrouping.

Comment: I need a list of all the duplicates found, so a list of both the A objects. Thanks

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, MyProject.Service.MyObject>> to System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.Services.MyObject>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var duplicates = allMyObjects.GroupBy(a => a.MyString)
                              .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
                              .SelectMany(g=>g)
                              .ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

you need to write

```
List<MyObject> duplicates = allMyObjects.GroupBy(a => a.MyString)
            .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This LINQ results in a `List<IGrouping<String, type-of-T-from-allMyObjects>>` (and can't be assigned to such a variable). The use of `SelectMany` should probably be considered.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problem, the first is a List-of-MyObject cannot be assigned to MyObject, so let's use `var` to ignore this for a second.

```
var duplicates = allMyObjects.GroupBy(a => a.MyString)
                   .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
                   .ToList();
```

Now, the type of `duplicates` is `List<IGrouping<string, MyObject>>` (despite the *incorrectly reported* error message). Whoops, gotta get rid of (or write to code to account for) the groups!

```
var duplicates = allMyObjects.GroupBy(a => a.MyString)
                   .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
                   .SelectMany(g => g)
                   .ToList();
```

Now the type of `duplicates` is `List<MyObject>`, after having selected every ("selected many") object from every group with more than one item. Better, but this still isn't an `MyObject`. Well, that's fine: fix the declared type of the variable (that `var` was previously automatically doing)..

```
List<MyObject> duplicates = /* same as before */;
```

Or leave `var` to do it's thing and if an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` is fine, simply omit the ToList:

```
var duplicates = allMyObjects.GroupBy(a => a.MyString)
                   .Where(a => a.Count() > 1)
                   .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Go forth and iterate thy duplicates!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ToLookup` to make a nice data structure with all the info you need

```
var objectsByString = allMyObjects.ToLookup(o => o.MyString);
```

This will return a `Lookup<string, MyObject>`. You can get the duplicate strings using:

```
var duplicateStrings = objectsByString.Where(l => l.Count()>1).Select(l => l.Key);
```

which will return a `IEnumerable<string>` with the duplicate strings. And, for each duplicate you can access the actual objects that have duplicates using something like this:

```
string duplicateKey = duplicateStrings.First();
var duplicateObjects = objectsByString[duplicateKey]
```

which returns a `IEnumerable<MyObject>` with the items that have that string.